# Variable substitution when integrating with Mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, lazy-computations

When I try to integrate this MMA freezes:

`II = (2 fx R Cos[ϕ] Sin[θ])/(R^2 + ρz^2 -  2 R ρz Cos[θ])^(3/2)`

`Integrate[II, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, {θ, 0, π}]`

But if I impose `ρz=0` the integral is very quickly solved. Any suggestions to why this happens and how to encourage MMA to find a useful substitution?

Comment: If you integrate stepwise it turns out `Integrate[II,{ϕ, 0, 2 π}]==0 ` !!! That means if the integral exists it will be `0`. Mathematica "freezes" the integration trying to transfform it to an elliptic form I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First:**

Your  integral equals `0` !

```
Integrate[II, {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]} ]
(*0*)
```

**Second:**

Mathematica evaluates in finite time (~84s) the integral if you provide additional condition `R>0`

```
Integrate[II, {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}   , {\[Theta], 0,\[Pi]}, Assumptions -> R > 0]
(*0*)
```

Comment: Mmm, I had an overall assumption on R>0, but it did not seem to work... As in `$Assumptions =...`. How would I add more assumptions to the integral calculation?

Comment: `...Assumptions -> {R > 0, rhoz<R,....}`